# How can I write a Java function to return the standard name for a Unicode point?

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding

I want to write a function

```
String getName(int codePoint) {
    // ????
}
```

which will return the standard name given to the character that the given code point represents.  For example

```
getName(0);
```

would return the String "NULL" and

```
getName(33);
```

would return the String "EXCLAMATION POINT".

Is there anything in the JDK for this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Lexical Tools Java 6.0, UTF-8 , 2009 Release](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/SPECIALIST/Projects/lvg/2009/index.html) mentioned by Ashalynd looks like it has a [Get Unicode Name](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/SPECIALIST/Projects/lvg/2009/docs/designDoc/UDF/unicode/NormOperations/getUnicodeName.html) feature.  However, behind the scenes it is using ICU4J from the [ICU Project](http://site.icu-project.org/).  ISU4J has a [UCharacter.getName()](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/lang/UCharacter.html#getName(int)) function that may be of use.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the [unicode standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is a file [UnicodeData-<Version>.txt](http://ftp.zcu.cz/mirrors/unicode/4.0-Update/UnicodeData-4.0.0.txt) (the download from unicode.org does not work) that contains the name (and reading direction, toLowerCase and toUpperCase etc.):

```
0021;EXCLAMATION MARK;Po;0;ON;;;;;N;;;;;
```

So *`0x21`* is called *EXCLAMATION MARK* by the unicode standard.

This could be buried somewhere in the JRE in some form as it is used to convert to lower and upper case characters.

Comment: or you could use that file to roll your own getName function

Answer (score 0):

No, the standard JDK does not come with that information. It can decode and encode in various schemes, but include all names in any packaging would require a huge download.

As pointed out, [The Specialist Lexical Tools](http://lexsrv3.nlm.nih.gov/LexSysGroup/index.html) might help. Beware. It is a 830 Mb donwload.